# Count number of keys in ordered dict that start with specific string

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddict

I'd like to count the number of strings in an ordered dict that start with a particular string.
For example, I have the following ordered dict:

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'First'), ('Size': '10'), ('Rate 1', '1000'), ('Rate 2', '100'), ('End', 'Last'])
```

I want to count the number of keys that start with "Rate". In this example, it would be 2.

I tried `n = len(o_dict.keys().startswith('Rate'))` with but this results in `AttributeError: 'odict_keys' object has no attribute 'startswith'`.

Any idea what to do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Iterate over the keys and check if they each start with `'Rate'`. The collection of keys doesn't have a `startswith`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict([('Name', 'First'), ('Size', '10'), ('Rate 1', '1000'), ('Rate 2', '100'), ('End', 'Last')])
cnt = sum([1 for key in od.keys() if key.startswith("Rate")])
print(cnt)
```

### Output

```
2
```